# How to set a parameter in rspec Cabybara test suite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

My question may have multiple answers. I am still new at this.

What I'm trying to do is route to a page with two different parameters set.

```
/users/2/edit?type=edit
/users/2/edit?type=password
```

I am able to get there when I physically go there:

## controller code:

```
def edit
    @edit_type = params[:type]
  end
```

## view code:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <% if current_user.admin? and @edit_type == 'edit' %>
            <%= f.label :username %>
            <%= f.text_field :username %>
        <% else%>
            <% if current_user?(@user) %>
                <%= f.label :curr_password, "Current Password" %>
                <%= f.password_field :curr_password %>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password %>

            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

but how do I get there from rspec with Capybara?

## test code:

```
 describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
    describe "page" do
      describe "as non-admin" do
        before do
          sign_in user
          visit edit_user_path(user)
        end
        it { should have_content("Update Password") }
        it { should have_title("Edit user") }
        it { should_not have_content("Username") }
      end
      describe "as admin " do
        # describe "visiting "
        before do
          sign_in admin
          visit edit_user_path(user)
        end
        # These all fail because it doesn't go to the right site (type is empty)
        it { should have_content("Update User Record") }
        it { should have_title("Edit user") }
        it { should  find_field("Username") }
      end
    end
. . .
```

## How do I set a parameter (?type='something') in rspec / Capybara?

Alternatively, could/should I be routing to this? something like:

```
/users/:id/edit/:type
```

How would I do that? How can I test it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just pass the `type` parameter into your route helper. In your admin test:

```
visit edit_user_path(user)
```

Should be something like:

```
visit edit_user_path(user, :type => "user")
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked very well. Should I do it this way, or should I do a route? Does it matter?